# Assigning binary fraction to float variable in C

Tags: c, floating-point, binary, fractions

I am trying to do something like as below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float a = 0b00000100;
    float b = 0b0.0110; // this line is not working
    printf("The value of first float is = %f\n", a * 15);
    printf("The value of second float is = %f\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

My only goal here is to assign `b` with the fractional binary number which is `0.0110` and should result in `0.375`. Anyone any idea?

Comment: C doesn't support binary floating point literals.

Comment: `double b = 0b00110 / 2. / 2. / 2. / 2.;` :-)

Comment: C23 introduces binary *integer* literals, which were previously a GCC langauge extension.

Comment: Aside: please use `double` wherever you can, the natural floating point type. The `float` is a relic from ancient textbooks when `double` was a bit frightening, andis  best used for a *specific* reason, such as a memory limitation.

Comment: Where did you see anything saying that's valid C syntax?

Comment: @Shawn They presumably assumed that they could use it because binary integer literals worked.

Answer (score 2):

The upcoming C23 Standard introduces the `0b0110` syntax for integers, but not for floating point values.

Instead of `float b = 0b0.0110;` you could write:

```
float b = 0b0110 / 16.F;
```

Or more with the explicit number of fractional bits:

```
float b = 0b0110 * 0x1p-4F;
```

And for older C99 compilers:

```
float b = 0x6p-4F;
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard C does not have binary floating constants, and note that binary integer constants were only recently added to the language with C23; previously binary integer constants like `0b00000100` were only available as implementation-specific extensions.

But C has had *hexadecimal* floating constants since C99. These are useful for working with binary representations. Each of the 16 hexadecimal digits corresponds to a four-digit binary sequence; if you learn these you can quickly write down the hexadecimal equivalent of a binary representation.

| Binary | Hexadecimal | Binary | Hexadecimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | 0 | 1000 | 8 |
| 0001 | 1 | 1001 | 9 |
| 0010 | 2 | 1010 | A |
| 0011 | 3 | 1011 | B |
| 0100 | 4 | 1100 | C |
| 0101 | 5 | 1101 | D |
| 0110 | 6 | 1110 | E |
| 0111 | 7 | 1111 | F |

The format of a hexadecimal floating constant in C is a hexadecimal prefix (`0x` or `0X`) followed by a hexadecimal fractional constant (e.g., `ABC.DEF`) followed by a (mandatory) binary exponent part. The binary exponent part must be prefixed by either `p` or `P` (e.g., `p-3`). Note that the binary exponent is expressed in *powers of 2* instead of powers of 10.

Hexadecimal floating constants have type `double` by default. If a hexadecimal floating constant is suffixed by `f` or `F` it has type `float`, and if suffixed by `l` or `L` it has type `long double`.

Referencing the table above the OP desired `0b0.0110` can be written in hexadecimal as `0x0.6p0` since `0110` is equivalent to the hexadecimal digit `6`. An exponent is required, and `p0` indicates that the significand should not be scaled.

Here is an example in code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // binary float: 0.0110
    double b = 0x0.6p0;

    // binary float: 1101 1110 1010 1101 . 1011 1110 1110 1111
    // hex float:     D    E    A    D   .  B    E    E    F
    double dead_beef = 0xDEAD.BEEFp0;
    double d_eadbeef = 0xD.EADBEEFp12; // `p12` moves the "decimal" point 12 binary digits to the right

    printf("b = %f\n", b);
    printf("dead_beef = %f\n", dead_beef);
    printf("d_eadbeef = %f\n", d_eadbeef);
}
```

```
> ./fc
b = 0.375000
dead_beef = 57005.745834
d_eadbeef = 57005.745834
```

Answer (score 0):

I quickly made this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

float binary_f(char fraction[]){
  char *pointp; //pointer to the point
  long integer=strtol(fraction, &pointp, 2); //Gives the integer and the pointer to the point, at the same time!
  int point=(int)(pointp-fraction);
  
  long div = 2;
  int lenght=strlen(fraction);
  float result=0;
  
  for (int i=point+1;i<lenght;i++){
    if (fraction[i]=='1'){
      result+=(float)1/div; 
    }
    div <<= 1; //Multiply the divisor by 2
  }
  return result+(float)integer;
}

int main() {
  char fractionary[]="10.001";
  float a=binary_f(fractionary);
  printf("%f",a);
  return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
2.125000
```

As you may notice, it isn't really robust, but it does the job for
it's expected parameters.